# Variable Declaration in If-Else Block not Recognized Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, variables

I just noticed the following strange behavior in Xcode:

```
if (post.count > 2) {
    NSString *reuseIdentifier = @"anIdentifier";
}
else {
    NSString *reuseIdentifier = @"anotherIdentifier";
}

[tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier]; // error: use of undeclared identifier 'reuseIdentifier'
```

Is there any reason why the compiler can't detect that `reuseIdentifier` will always be declared? This is on Xcode 5.1.1. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you misunderstand variable scoping. It's important to declare the variable in the scope where you are going to use it. The first reuseIdentifier is a local variable valid only in the if{} block, and the second one a local variable to the else{} block. The way to be sure and make the code is correct and readable is as follows:

```
NSString *reuseIdentifier; //available in this entire function
if (post.count > 2) {
    reuseIdentifier = @"anIdentifier";
}
else {
    reuseIdentifier = @"anotherIdentifier";
}

[tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
```

Comment: As an aside, I see a few downvotes to the question. I don't concur. I think downvotes make sense when the question is poorly formed, off-topic, or shows an insufficient lack of effort. The question may have reflected an important misunderstanding (and the OP assumed it was an XCode validation problem, not a genuine code problem), but there was sample code and the question itself was clear...

Answer (score 1):

You need to do it this way:

```
NSString *reuseIdentifier;

if (post.count > 2) {
     reuseIdentifier  = @"anIdentifier";
}
else {
    reuseIdentifier = @"anotherIdentifier";
}

[tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier]; // error: use of undeclared identifier 'reuseIdentifier'
```

The problem the way you did it was that reuseIdentifier in each scope is local to the if/else scope.

Answer (score 1):

Because the variable `NSString *reuseIdentifier` scope is only inside the condition. You need to declare the same outside the condition. So you can make your code short and precise like that below:-

```
NSString *reuseIdentifier = (post.count > 2) ? @"anIdentifier" : @"anotherIdentifier";
[tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
```